# access is denied when trying to upload image to the server using asp.net web api 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to upload image to the server with WebAPI
C# Code:

```
 public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];

                    var filename = postedFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();

                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"+ filename);

                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    return "/uploads" + filename;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "file was not uploaded";
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message;
        }
        return "hi";
    }
```

When I upload image through postman, I get

> "Access to the path 'c:\users\ahmed\source\repos\Election\Election\Uploads\Background.png' is denied."

Comment: my guess would be that the iis/application user doesn't have access to save in the c:\users\ahmed directory as this directory is only accessible by your user account. Try saving in a folder directly on c drive. like c:/temp or try copying the solution and executing it from outside your user directory.

Comment: Yes check the permissions of the folder, the same error was for me checked all permission of the root folder and then worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your upload folder permissions. And add everyone permission to upload folder, and test it again. Don't forget remove everyone permission when test is over.

Comment: thank you it worked, i forgot about it.  appreciate it

Comment: it worked locally, but when i run from the azure cloud i get this error

Comment: "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\Uploads\\Background.png'."

Comment: i solved thank you and it is now uploading to azure, thank you for your time